# i would like to know any good mcq book on multi variable calculus.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can anyone suggest a good book involving  large no. Of questions on several variable functions  involving partial derivatives, higher order partial derivatives and Lagrange's multipliers ?

Comment: Schuam's books are good - they have short resume's of the topics, then a whole bunch of worked exercises and then additional questions.  Check out Murray R Spiegel's Advanced Calculus - it has good coverage of all the topics you mention.